# What is the difference between alloc, retain and copy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

This might seem a simple question, but I don't really get the idea of when should I use alloc, retain or copy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please go through [this](http://humblecoder.blogspot.com/2009/08/iphone-tutorial-memory-management.html) long tutorial on memory management. It may require some time to read whole, but it explains the basic things nicely.

EDIT : About copy -
When you are using retain then you are just increasing the retain count of the object. But when you use copy, a separate copy (shallow copy) of the object is created. Separate means it is a different object with retain count 1.

For example,

```
NSObject *obj1 = [[NSObject alloc] init];   // obj1 has retain count 1

// obj1 and obj2 both refer same object. now retain count = 2
// any change via obj1 will be seen by obj2 and vice versa, as they point same object
NSObject *obj2 = [obj1 retain];   

// obj3 is a separate copy of the object. its retain count is 1 just like newly allocated object
// change via obj3 will not affect obj1 or obj2 and vice versa as they are separate objects
NSObject *obj3 = [obj1 copy];
```

Comment: Thanks.  The tutorial does explain what retain means and quite a lot of basic memory management, but it doesn't really explain what the copy method does.  Is there any more tutorials on memory management or just the alloc memory part? Thanks

Comment: And also when you get time, check the detail guide on memory management suggested by William Remacle.

Comment: It's worth noting that `-copy` does not always create a "separate copy of the object." In the case of immutable Foundation classes (e.g. `NSString`, `NSArray`, etc.) there is no need to duplicate the object as it will never change -- the `-copy` method simply retains the object.

Answer (score 4):

**Alloc** : when you need to make memory allocations (You want to create an object, you need to allocate memory space for it)

Each object has a retain count which indicates the number of objects with an ownership interest in that object. It's automatically done with **alloc** and with **copy** (copy means you want a copy of that object). But you can also do it by using **retain** keyword.

When retain count == 0, the object **dealloc** method will be called and will release all allocations made in that object.

I hope it is clear enough.
If you want more information : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html